# Is backed up system with TWRP safe for reflashing?

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, line

Suppose I have a device that has TWRP installed, and a complete backup performed to internal storage via TWRP.

Is it always safe to flash a custom ROM (for example, LineageOS) given the above conditions, even ROMs that are not compatible with the device? (since it should be possible to restore via TWRP's backup)

Comment: Safe against what? If the backup is saved in internal storage a simple "clear storage" will delete the backup.

Comment: @Robert safe against flashing a new ROM, like LineageOS. That is, will TWRP be inaccessible for restoring to a known-good config after flashing a bad/incompatible ROM?

Comment: When flashing anew ROM "clear storage" is a checkbox - I don't know if it is check by default or not. But in general you should not store important data on the phone when you flash something new. Some ROMs even contain empty user data partitions, which is effectively the same as "clear user data".

Comment: "safe" is subjective here... if you mess up the system, then you may not be able to restore the system. Flashing an incompatible ROM could cause damage beyond what a nandroid restore can fix, as flashing a ROM may repartition the system, change filesystem formats, or overwrite things not in an nandroid backup. There is no generic answer to your question...